# Can I "Hide" Columns In MySQL?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007

```
        con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select DISTINCT DesignationDate as [Date], DayNumber as [DN] from employeedesignation where employeeID = '" & EmployeeID3.Text & "' order by DayNumber asc", con)
        Dim myDA As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

        Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()

        myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "EmployeeDesignation")

        dgridempinfo_4.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDesignation").DefaultView

        con.Close()
```

This code just fills in my datagrid "dgridempinfo_4", and shows 2 columns, DATE and DN.

I can hide the column by datagrid property or code, but can I query such that DN will not show in the statement itself?

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit - why do you include it in the query if you don't want it in the output?

Comment: So I can use order by. Might be primitive but it's what I know. :(

Comment: No worries! You don't need to include a column in the output list in order to sort by it. So change your query to this: `Select DISTINCT DesignationDate as [Date] from employeedesignation where employeeID = '" & EmployeeID3.Text & "' order by DayNumber asc`

Comment: Yes I have tried that once and this error was new to me "ORDER BY clause (DayNumber) conflicts with DISTINCT." :(

Comment: You are right - sorry about that. Can you tell me if you are using MySQL or MS Access, because I see you have both in the tags?

Comment: Oops. My bad. MS Access, OLE DB. :D

Comment: If it's Access then take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734584/order-by-clause-conflicts-with-distinct-in-access. It recommends using **group by** instead of **distinct**. It should work with your scenario. Matthew's suggestion is also good if you don't want to deal with the  query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the column in your query, to perhaps perform additional extraction of data, but do not want to display this within your view, then you can always remove the columns you want hidden after filling your dataset:

```
table(0).Columns.Remove("Foo")
```

You can also specify an index instead of the name, but make sure you get your index right!:

```
table(0).Columns.Remove(0)
```