# Select Multiple distinct with Order By Date Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by, distinct, ms-access-2013

I have a MS-Access database tabel with follwing structure and Data :

[image]

Now i want all the columns in my result with following conditions :

1. **TicketNo** should not be repeated in result
2. Result should be sorted by date Column (**EnteredDate**)

I tried some examples from StackOverflow as well as some other sources but didn't get desired result.

I Tried to Use :

1. KeyWord **DISTINCT** and **GROUP BY** and **ORDER BY** (Obviously in different queries)
2. **MAX** and **MIN** according to some examples.

Please help me find the solution.
Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with your try? no1 and 2?

Comment: try to use the query wizard in Access. It makes it easier to create a query for novices

Comment: @DonDjoe : Word **DISTINCT** conflicts with **Order By** clause.

Comment: @cha : Thanks but tried. Didn't helped much. For me, it is helpful for multiple table query.

Comment: for no 1. You can drop `distinct` and just use `group by` i believe. In fact you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734584/order-by-clause-conflicts-with-distinct-in-access. I just don't have ms access to test it

Comment: Yes. I tried that actually read that post before. But that didn't helped me.

Comment: If "TicketNo should not be repeated in result" then what date/time should be displayed for, say, ticket no. 3000?

Comment: Sorry not to mention that. It should be by DESC order. e.g. Only one TicketNo 3000 but with latest timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**[EDIT]**

```
SELECT src.ID, src.TicketNo, src.TicketQuantity, src.TicketRate, src.EnteredDate
FROM (
    SELECT TicketNo, MAX(EnteredDate) AS MaxEnteredDate
    FROM Tickets
    GROUP BY TicketNo
 ) AS mtn INNER JOIN Tickets AS src ON mtn.TicketNo = src.TicketNo AND mtn.MaxEnteredDate = src.EnteredDate
ORDER BY src.EnteredDate DESC
```

Above query returns:

```
ID  TicketNo    TicketQuantity  TicketRate  EnteredDate
6   3000        3               2           2015-01-11 18:27:39
5   3002        6               2           2015-01-11 18:27:31
2   3001        2               2           2015-01-11 18:27:15
```

Comment: Got this error :

>Circular Reference caused by alias 'TicketNo' in query definition's select list

Comment: @MahadevMalkar, are you sure, you re-write query carefully? Note that i'm using aliases for table names.

Comment: I got the result but strangely query returned whole Table as result. Exactly same as posted in Question.

Comment: OK, i need some time to re-create the issue. I'll post an answer ASAP.

Comment: @MahadevMalkar, Done! The logic for subquery was wrong. We need to get TicketNo for MAX(EnteredDate) ;)